# Using PHP foreach to get mysql table data

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

ive got 1 database table contains row:

TABLE FROM reservations:

```
attandee01  
attandee02  
attandee03  
attandee04  
attandee05  
attandee06
```

PHP CODE:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bs_events
LEFT JOIN bs_reservations ON bs_reservations.id_event = bs_events.id");

while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
   echo '<td>' . $r['attandee1'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $r['attandee2'] . '</td>'
   echo '<td>' . $r['attandee3'] . '</td>'
endwhile;
```

or is there any simple way using foreach to echo attandee1 - attandee10?

Comment: Why dobn't you use `mysql_` ? database is sensitive specially on large websites , using classes to deal with the database might slowdown your server .

Comment: @Ronan Congratulations, you won "Most ridiculous comment" award!

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel lol , but have you ever been the owner of a large website that gets like 5 million page views a day ? and there were no place to use caching because the data need to be up-to-date ?

Comment: You should consider changing your DB design... it seems you have hardcoded the number of attendees.

Comment: @Ronan Congratulations - you won the `2nd Most ridiculous comment` as well ... 5 million page view does not mean you can not apply cache ...

Comment: @ajreal you cannot apply caching because you need to have the information up-to-date and not because of the 5 million pvs ... seems you wont the same award as me hehehe

Comment: you must be joking - the fundamental meaning of caching - read once, used many until time-to-live reached ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bs_events
LEFT JOIN bs_reservations ON bs_reservations.id_event = bs_events.id");

while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
   foreach($r as $value) {
       echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
   }
endwhile;
```

Should echo each column value per table row.

EDIT: If you only want the attendees:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bs_events
LEFT JOIN bs_reservations ON bs_reservations.id_event = bs_events.id");

while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
   for($i = 1; $i < 11 $i++) {
       echo '<td>' . $r['attendee'.$i] . '</td>';
   }
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach, of course, as `$r` is a regular array and can be iterated using foreach() operator. Did you try it?

However, looking at the field names, I suspect serious design flaw in your data structure.
It seems attandees should be stored in another table.

You may also consider using *templates*. Printing data directly from the database loop is very bad practice. You have to get all your data first and only then start printing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes:

```
for($i=1; $i<11; ++$i) {
  echo "<td>".$r["attandee".$i]. "</td>";
}
```

But that is columns, what you want is the row based solution for that I'd use something like:

```
for($r=$q->fetch_assoc(); !is_null($r); $r= $q->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<td>".array_pop($r)."</td>"; // output the only element in the array?
}
$q->free(); // don't forget to free the memory of the result set!
```

Comment: thanks! just like i wanted! but it echoing the row that is empty!

Answer (score 1):

don't know if i understood your question... is this what you're looking for:

```
while($row = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
    foreach($row as $field){
       echo '<td>' . $field . '</td>';
    }
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is what you are looking for, but give it a shot:

```
while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   foreach($r as $value) {
      echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As example you can use alternate syntax.

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($mysqli->query($sql) as $row ): ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row['row_name1']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['row_name2']; ?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</table>
```